# What mech types and variants are in the game?

Tags: battletech

Navigating through the in game interface is a bit cumbersome, so I'm looking for a complete list of all mech types and variants in the game, including statistics like hardpoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki has a good listing, along with hardpoints.  There are many mechs.

As of release, here is the base list of chassis, some have multiple variants:

- Locust
- Commando
- Spider
- Urbanmech
- Firestarter
- Jenner
- Panther
- Cicada
- Blackjack
- Vindicator
- Centurion
- Enforcer
- Hunchback
- Trebuchet
- Griffin
- Kintaro
- Shadow Hawk
- Wolverine
- Dragon
- Quickdraw
- Catapult
- Jagermech
- Thunderbolt
- Cataphract
- Grasshopper
- Black Knight
- Orion
- Awesome
- Victor
- Zeus
- Battlemaster
- Stalker
- Highlander
- Banshee
- Atlas
- King Crab

https://battletech.gamepedia.com/Battlemechs

Answer (score 1):

An updated for 1.6

There are roughly 65 mechs in the base game, some mechs have more than one variant, for example there are currently three variants of the Thunderbolt.

The Flashpoint expansion added:

- Hatchman
- Crab (with the custom Big Steel Claw variant)
- Cyclops

The Urban Warfare expansion adds (based on news reports):

- Raven
- Javelin

1.6 added variants for:

- UrbanMech
- Blackjack
- Hatchman (Requires Flashpoint)
- Catapult
- Banshee